# How to count multiple variables in dataset a pipe by incorporating the grep function?

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, grepl

I need to count multiple variables in a dataset in one go using a pipe.

I have used the following code:

```
#R
NonComp_Strat <- Minor_Behaviours %>% 
filter(Categories == "Non compliant with routine") %>% 
group_by(Strategies) %>% 
summarise(frequency= n())
```

However, in my data frame some cells contain multiple entries separated by a comma.

For example

It treats the following behaviour entries differently, "Disruptive" , and "Disruptive, Off Task".

Both behaviour entries in the data frame have the variable i am looking for but i don't know how to wrap the grep or grepl function into the pipe to count all the individual variables. There are over 20 of them and doing over 20 individual grep functions sounds terrible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks,

Dan

Comment: I do not understand it. Can you show it for two variables how it would look like? I don´t know if you want to dynamically filter or group_by.

Comment: The problem I have is that people have selected multiple strategies for a single behaviour entry. 1 cell that has 3 strategies listed such as, Detention, Brief Time Out, Interview. My problem is when i use the group_by verb for "Strategies" in R it treats someone who has entered "Detention" once differently from someone who has entered "Detention, Brief Time Out, Interview". I want to be able to get the totals for all the different strategies used without doing individual grep functions for each different strategy. Does that make more sense?

Comment: So when someone has listed "Detention, Brief Time Out, Interview", you want this to be counted for all 3 of these?

Comment: I want to count each one individually. But R counts the combination once.

Answer (score 1):

You will first have to split the comma separated values and make new rows out of them. Then you can `group_by` as you were doing:

```
library(splitstackshape)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:4), Strategies = c("Disruptive", "Disruptive, Off Task", "Off Task", "Off Task, Interview"))
df
  id           Strategies
1  1           Disruptive
2  2 Disruptive, Off Task
3  3             Off Task
4  4  Off Task, Interview
df <- cSplit(df, "Strategies", ",", "long")
df
   id Strategies
1:  1 Disruptive
2:  2 Disruptive
3:  2   Off Task
4:  3   Off Task
5:  4   Off Task
6:  4  Interview
```

Answer (score 0):

In one `dplyr` and `tidyr` workflow:

```
df %>%
    separate(Strategies, paste("Strategies", 1:5, sep = "_"), extra = "drop", sep = ",") %>%
    gather(Stacked, Strategies, Strategies_1:Strategies_5) %>%
    select(-Stacked) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    mutate(Strategies = as.factor(trimws(Strategies))) %>%
    group_by(Strategies) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) 



  Strategies     count
  <fct>          <int>
1 Brief Time Out     1
2 Detention          2
3 Disruptive         2
4 Interview          1
5 Off Task           1
```

Answer (score 0):

More general we could design a split function that produces `reshape`able data.

```
spltCol <- function(x) {
  l <- strsplit(as.character(x), ", ?")
  l <- lapply(l, function(y) c(y, rep(NA, max(lengths(l)) - length(y))))
  return(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, l)))
}
```

**Example**

```
df1
#   id                  x          z
# 1  1 alpha, beta, gamma  0.7281856
# 2  2        alpha, beta -0.3149730
# 3  3              alpha -2.6412875
# 4  4               <NA>  0.6412990

df12 <- data.frame(append(df1[-2], spltCol(df1$x)))
#   id          z    V1   V2    V3
# 1  1  0.7281856 alpha beta gamma
# 2  2 -0.3149730 alpha beta  <NA>
# 3  3 -2.6412875 alpha <NA>  <NA>
# 4  4  0.6412990  <NA> <NA>  <NA>

reshape(df12, direction="long", varying=cbind("V1", "V2", "V3"), v.names=names(df1)[2])
#     id          z time     x
# 1.1  1  0.7281856    1 alpha
# 2.1  2 -0.3149730    1 alpha
# 3.1  3 -2.6412875    1 alpha
# 4.1  4  0.6412990    1  <NA>
# 1.2  1  0.7281856    2  beta
# 2.2  2 -0.3149730    2  beta
# 3.2  3 -2.6412875    2  <NA>
# 4.2  4  0.6412990    2  <NA>
# 1.3  1  0.7281856    3 gamma
# 2.3  2 -0.3149730    3  <NA>
# 3.3  3 -2.6412875    3  <NA>
# 4.3  4  0.6412990    3  <NA>
```

***Data***

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:4, x = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("alpha", 
"alpha, beta", "alpha, beta, gamma"), class = "factor"), z = c(0.72818559355044, 
-0.314973049072542, -2.64128753187138, 0.641298995312115)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```